# Why my report has strange fonts when I export it to PDF file?

Tags: crystal-reports, fonts, crystal-reports-8.5

Hi
I have a report which has been created by Crystal Reports 8.5.
When I run my application (vb6) and wanna show the report, every thing is all right but problem begins when I export it to PDF file. The .pdf file has strange fonts and can NOT be read .

I have used "Tahoma" font for displaying text on the report.

What is your solution? Is there any solution?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your .rpt got corrupted somehow?  Try building a new test report from scratch and use the same setup to export it to PDF.  If that works, then you'll probably have to rewrite your real report from scratch.

Comment: No, it hs Not beed corrupted, I think the problem is related to Font issue